# createElement("a") - FireFox JavaScript

Tags: javascript, hyperlink, createelement

i have problem. I have an iframe(editable) and when i click the button i will create a link. So that's not the problem. But, after this i stay in the "link" mode. I have only this problem in FireFox. What's wrong. Thx a lot.

JavaScript Function in index.php

```
    function insertLink(verlinkung,text) 
    {
        var doc = document.getElementById("frame").contentWindow.document;      
        var sel = doc.getSelection();

        if (sel.rangeCount > 0)
        {
            var range= sel.getRangeAt(0);

myParent=document.getElementById("frame").contentWindow.document.body;
            alink=document.createElement("a");

            text= document.createTextNode(text);

            alink.href = verlinkung;
            if (document.getElementById('check_underline').checked == false)
            {
                alink.setAttribute("style","text-decoration: none;");
            }
            else
            {
                alink.setAttribute("style","text-decoration: underline;");
            }
            alink.appendChild(text);

            myParent.appendChild(alink);
            range.insertNode(alink);

        }
    }
```

-- in the same site like the javascript function

```
<img src ='./images/toolbar/plus.png' onMouseDown = "insertLink(document.getElementById('link_href').value,document.getElementById('link_text').value);">
```

in Index.php

```
<iframe src = './editor.php' id = 'frame' class = 'iframe_design'>
```

Content of the Iframe in editor.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"> 

    <script language = 'JavaScript'>
        function lade()
        {
            document.body.contentEditable='true';
            document.designMode='on';
            void 0;
}

</head>  

<body style = 'font-family: verdana; font-size: small;'>

</body>

</html>
```

So, and when i create a Link with the image Click, i stay in the "hyperlink" mode. Only in FireFox. So i can write a normal text, but it works like a hyperlink.

Comment: *`But, after this i stay in the "link" mode`*? Can you be just a bit more specific?

Comment: When i want to write after the insert of the link. the whole text will be a link.

Comment: Would you be able to post any HTML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're doing should work.

Try this simplified version:

```
<div id="x">A link should appear here: </div>

<script>
    var a = document.createElement("a");
    var text = document.createTextNode("I'm a link");
    a.setAttribute("style", "text-decoration: underline;");
    a.setAttribute("href", "https://github.com/adrianblynch?tab=repositories");
    a.appendChild(text);
    document.getElementById("x").appendChild(a);
</script>
```

Works for me in Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: OK, but i use an editable iframe, so the insert works without problems, but after the insert, this is my problem

Comment: Could you reduce your code down to something resembling the above? It'll make it easier to debug.

Comment: Thx a lot, but now i have another problem. I can't change the color of this link with execommand. I tried it with execommand("styleWithCss".....) and without. Nothing happens. I can change the font-size and font-family but not the color why not?

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I could find so far, was to make sure there was some extra content after the link, but still within the same parent i.e. the `<p>` or `body` tag. I've done this by appending an invisible character `&zwnj` straight after the hyperlink. This solves the problem you currenly have, but using this you will have to devise a clean, non-interfering way to remove these special characters.

You could remove instances that are no longer required i.e. zwnjs that are surround by text, either:

1. after a delay from `onkeyup`.
2. when you save or export the content.
3. when the user refocuses the caret.

> Note: if left for too long it is possible for the user to discover their presence, or at least notice a strange behaviour. For example, if you write some text after a newly inserted link, but then decide to delete that text and the link you'll notice a one character pause when holding down the delete key. So it would be best to remove them as soon as they are no longer required.

Below you'll find a working demo. My code isn't using an iframe, but you could easily modify it back to operating in that manner.

```js
function insertLink(verlinkung, text) {
  var doc = document, sel = doc.getSelection();
  if ( sel.rangeCount > 0 ) {
    var range = sel.getRangeAt(0), 
        myParent = document.getElementById('editable'),
        docFragment = range.createContextualFragment('<a href="' + verlinkung + '">' + text + '</a>&zwnj;');
    range.insertNode(docFragment);
  }
}
```

```css
html, body { height: 100%; }

.editable {
  width: 500px;
  height: 400px;
  border: 1px dotted gray;
  padding: 10px;
}

button {
  background: orange;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 0;
  padding: 8px;
  margin-top: 8px;
}

p {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
}
```

```html
<div id="editable" class="editable" ContentEditable="true">
<p>
Focus your caret at the end of this text and click "Add Link", then place the caret after the new link and type some text. The text should not be part of the link.
</p>
<p>
The only way I could stop Firefox from placing the caret inside the link's range, and so not inserting new content inside it, was to make sure there was some content after it.
</p>
<p>
Using <strong>&amp;zwnj;</strong> &mdash; <em>zero width non-joiner</em> &mdash; means that you can have an invisible character, that isn't treated as whitespace (and so isn't automatically removed). The downside to this method is that you'll need to find a point where you can safely remove these special characters. You could wait until you are saving/exporting your editor content &mdash; but if you wait until then it is possible the user will notice their existence when deleting characters.
</p>
</div>
<button onclick="insertLink('#test', 'Test')">Add Link</button>
```